# Best (or appropriate) WSGI server for this Python script? - Python

Tags: python, concurrency, mod-wsgi, wsgi, cherrypy

I'm having quite a problem deciding how to serve a few Python scripts.

The problem is that the basic functionality could be generalized by this:

```
do_something()
time.sleep(3)
do_something()
```

---

I tried various **WSGI servers**, but they have all been giving me concurrency limitations, as in I have to specify how many threads to use and so on.

I only wish that the resources on the server be used efficiently and liberally.

---

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked tornado with its non-blocking asynchronous requests?

http://www.tornadoweb.org/

I have never used it though but here is an example from doc:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http.fetch("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/bret",
                   callback=self.async_callback(self.on_response))

    def on_response(self, response):
        if response.error: raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
        json = tornado.escape.json_decode(response.body)
        self.write("Fetched " + str(len(json["entries"])) + " entries "
                   "from the FriendFeed API")
        self.finish()
```

Comment: @hadrienL for some reason it only serves 1 request at a time :|

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning) a good fit.  It has several options for deployment, one of which is somewhat transparent async (as implemented by [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/)).  So if you literally do `time.sleep(3)` it'll be okay.  Not everything you might do is transparently handled, so you have to pay some attention to Eventlet and how it works.  Sockets are, for instance, so if you read from a socket (and that socket blocks) it won't halt the server or consume a thread.  But if you do CPU-heavy work that will block all requests.  So... it's a bit tricky.  Spawning has some other deployment options that might work for you too.

You might be able to use [WaitForIt](http://pythonpaste.org/waitforit/), though it has some gotchas.  It will spawn threads for long-running requests, and provides some browser feedback, so if you are creating a very simplistic frontend to long-running backend processes it might be useful.  It acts as WSGI middleware.

Answer (score 0):

What about CherryPy WSGI server?

What does that `sleep` mean? Are you really writing a web application?

Comment: @Messa: thanks for the reply! sleep means that for a second the script is not doing anything for 3 seconds. I tried CherryPy WSGI server, but it requires me to choose how many threads to use and this is currently the main limitation.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that CherryPy WSGI server manages thread count dynamically, but I have now looked on its source code and I don't think so anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

So it's OK for the client to be tied up waiting for an answer for 3 seconds, but not OK for the server? That seems...odd.

If you'd rather *not* have the client tied up for 3 seconds, a common mechanism is to have the initial request return "202 Accepted" ASAP with a URL to a status monitor. Then the server can spawn a new thread or subprocess for the task, and the client can do other things, and then poll the status URL to find out when the task is done.